# Update ArcGIS Online map from ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-pro

I know I can create a map using hosted features from my ArcGIS Online account, and eventually publish it as a web map. But what I can't find is how to open one of these existing maps (this step is easy), make modifications to it, and then save it back to Online.

Is it possible?

Comment: What are the precise steps that you have performed to get to where you are currently stuck?

Comment: It's been some time now, and we decided to stay with Desktop due to the obvious instability/performance drawbacks from Pro.

Still, if I remember correctly:
- Open the map from the right pane (Catalog's equivalent), in the web content list linked to our Online account.
- Made some modifications to the map.
- Tried to save it and bounced back to a "This map already exists" message